# Can I use named groups in a Perl regex to get the results in a hash?

Tags: python, regex, perl

Is it possible to perform a named-group match in Perl's regex syntax as with Python's? I always bind the `$n` values to proper names after matching, so I'd find it more convenient to do it in the regex itself if it's possible.

Python does it like so:

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r'(?P<count>\d+)')
>>> match = regex.match('42')
>>> print match.groupdict()
{'count': '42'}
```

I know the `?P` indicates that it's a Python-specific regex feature, but I'm hoping it's in Perl in a different way or was added later on. Is there any way to get a result hash in a similar manner in Perl?

Comment: For search engine findability: 

named groups are sometimes also referred to as "symbolic group names".

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Perl uses `(?<NAME>pattern)` to specify names captures. You have to use the `%+` hash to retrieve them.

```
$variable =~ /(?<count>\d+)/;
print "Count is $+{count}";
```

This is only supported on Perl 5.10 and higher though.

Comment: You can also use `%-` to access the captures.

Comment: This answer has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Groups".

Comment: the answer intended to say "You have to use the `$+` hash to retrieve them" correct ?

Comment: No I mean %+, but inflection means you access its members as $+{key}. It's a perl-ism that gets many outsiders confused.

Answer (score 21):

As of Perl 5.10, Perl regexes support [some Python features](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#PCRE%2fPython-Support), making them *Python* compatible regexes, I guess. The Python versions have the "P" in them, but all of these work in Perl 5.10. See the [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) documentation for the details:

Define a named capture buffer. Equivalent to `(?<NAME>pattern)`.

```
(?P<NAME>pattern)
```

Backreference to a named capture buffer. Equivalent to `\g{NAME}`.

```
(?P=NAME)
```

Subroutine call to a named capture buffer. Equivalent to `(?&NAME)`.

```
(?P>NAME)
```

Although I didn't add the Python-compatibility to the latest edition of [Learning Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596520106/), we do cover the new Perl 5.10 features, including named captures.

Comment: Please clarify which is the Perl syntax and which the Python.

Comment: The syntax with the extra P is python.

Comment: I have tried them all to see which work in Perl.
Yes, all of them can be used in latest Perl.

Answer (score 13):

As couple of people said perl 5.10 has named groups.

But in previous perls you can do something, not as convenient, but relatively nice:

```
my %hash;
@hash{"count", "something_else"} = $string =~ /(\d+)\s*,\s*(\S+)/;
```

and then you can use:

$hash{"count"} and $hash{"something_else"}.

Answer (score 5):

AFIK [PCRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCRE) has named group capturing as:

```
(?'NAME'pattern)
(?<NAME>pattern)
```

You can find info [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns).

Answer (score 0):

I use the [`%{^CAPTURE}`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#%25%7B%5ECAPTURE%7D) hash (for readability).

It is [English](https://perldoc.perl.org/English) version for `%+` as mentioned above by Leon Timmermans.

For example, a code I wrote for capturing PHP version:

```perl
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use v5.32;
use warnings;
use English;

my $output = `php -v`;

$output =~ m(PHP (?<version>\d.\d.\d\d)); # named capture group

say ${^CAPTURE}{version}; # instead of $1
```

Within the regex pattern you can reference the named capture groups as [`\g{NAME}`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#%5Ck%7BNAME%7D).

[TIMTOWTDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it) with Perl, so use the one which suits you the best.